# How to retrieve the data's from Firebase database and store it as a string?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i want to retrieve the rates in the firebase database and store it in an String, can anyone suggest me how to take the values alone from the database. i used this code and cannot get any values.i have added my database image for reference

```
     DatabaseReference rootRef =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                                    getReference("fish-market-ukkadam");
     ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String rates = ds.getValue(String.class);

                Log.d("TAG", rates);
            }


        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    };
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

[MY DATABASE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4toBA.png)

Comment: in your log the rates is stored?

Comment: no i want to add all the rates in one string, can you help me to store that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("fish-market-ukkadam");
```

With this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Your database project name is "fish-market-ukkadam", but that is not the name of the root node that you can access by name.

Comment: Process: fishmarket.xpensiver.com.fishmarket, PID: 9456
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzaC(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)  at fishmarket.xpensiver.com.fishmarket.listcheck_activity$1.onDataChange(listcheck_activity.java:29)
 at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)

Comment: THANKS now i am getting the values

Comment: Doug , just add `long rates = ds.getValue(Long.class);` for future readers